# Is there a relation between weak-* convergence in $L^\infty((0,T); L^2(\Omega))$ and strong convergence in $L^2(\Omega)$ uniformly in $t$?

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces, strong-convergence

I have problems in understanding a proof.
So my question is:

Let $u_n$ be a sequence that converges weak-* in $L^\infty((0,T); L^2(\Omega))$ to $u$. Can I imply that $u_n$ converges strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ uniformly in $t \in \left[0,T\right]$?
Or is there something similiar I can imply?

Here, $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T > 0$.

Comment: Consider the case when $u_{n}(t,x) = f_{n}(t)$ depends only on $t$, not $x$.